# Disable window beforeunload property for one button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have disabled page redirects/reloads with window.beforeunload function, but once the form submission happens in the page, I want to redirect to the next page, without showing the window.beforeunload alerts. How can I do that?

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function () {
    return "Changes won't be saved.";
});
```

This is the button that shouldn't trigger the alert:

```
<form id="command" action="/some-uri" method="post">
  <button type="submit" value="NEXT" class="btn btn-red-   light">NEXT</button>
</form>
```

Comment: So perhaps use a click handler on that button (or submit handler on that form) to remove your beforeonload handler?

Comment: write a submit event for form and add `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`

Answer (score 1):

Check a variable

pseudo code

```
if some dirty change ->  window.hasSomeDirtyChanges = true;
if all dirty changes saved -> window.hasSomeDirtyChanges = false;

$(window).on("beforeunload", function () {
    if(!window.hasSomeDirtyChanges) return true;
    return "Changes won't be saved.";
});
```

So this way you don't have to bind unbind every time you go to a page. This will work for all the pages, you just need to manage a variable.

Answer (score 0):

add a class to every element that you don't want to trigger the event, for example ".not-trigger", then:

```
$(".not-trigger").on("click", function(){
   $(window).off("beforeonunload");
});
```